How to build custom skill blocks in hugoblox
I am creating a group web page using https://hugoblox.com/templates/details/research-group/
I want the new skills (Teaching) to be added in individual profile. So, I followed https://bootstrap.hugoblox.com/blocks/skills/
Following that, I have done:
content/people/index.md:
---
title: People
date: 2022-10-24

type: landing

sections:
  - block: people
    content:
      title: Meet the Team
      # Choose which groups/teams of users to display.
      #   Edit `user_groups` in each user's profile to add them to one or more of these groups.
      user_groups:
          - Principal Investigators
          - Researchers
          - Grad Students
          - Administration
          - Visitors
          - Alumni
      sort_by: Params.last_name
      sort_ascending: true
    design:
      show_interests: false
      show_role: true
      show_social: true
  - block: skills
    content:
      title: Skills
      text: ''
      # Choose a user to display skills from (a folder name within `content/authors/`)
      username: admin
    design:
      columns: '1'
---

and in content/authors/admin/_index.md,
---
# Display name
title: Nelson Bighetti

# Full Name (for SEO)
first_name: Nelson
last_name: Bighetti

# Is this the primary user of the site?
superuser: true

# Role/position
role: Professor of Artificial Intelligence

# Organizations/Affiliations
organizations:
  - name: Stanford University
    url: ''

# Short bio (displayed in user profile at end of posts)
bio: My research interests include distributed robotics, mobile computing and programmable matter.

interests:
  - Artificial Intelligence
  - Computational Linguistics
  - Information Retrieval

education:
  courses:
    - course: PhD in Artificial Intelligence
      institution: Stanford University
      year: 2012
    - course: MEng in Artificial Intelligence
      institution: Massachusetts Institute of Technology
      year: 2009
    - course: BSc in Artificial Intelligence
      institution: Massachusetts Institute of Technology
      year: 2008

skills:
  - name: Technical
    items:
    - name: Python
      description: ''
      percent: 80
      icon: python
      icon_pack: fab
   ...more lines...

But this is not creating the skills into the user's profile, but at the bottom of "Meet the people" page.
I would like each of the members to have different teaching showing in there profile.
How I can achieve that?

You need to create separate pages for each person, and add the content related to the skills in the page of each person, not in the admin/_index.md (this was an example given on the tutorial)
For example, if you have 3 authors, you can create these 3 pages and add the skills in each one.
content/authors/john/_index.md
content/authors/daniel/_index.md
content/authors/jessica/_index.md

